# Measurable Space of Measures

Tags: probability-theory

We have a definition for the usual measurable space of $\sigma$-finite measures on $S$ given by:

It is the measurable space when endowed with the $\sigma$-field induced by the mappings $\pi_B$:$\mu\to\mu B$ for $B\in S$.

What does this space actually mean? How does a measurable subset of it look like?

I ask because he goes to state that:

The mapping $(\mu,\nu)\to\mu\times\nu$ is measurable from $P(S)\times P(T)$ to $P(S\times T)$ where $P(X)$ is the set of probability measures on $X$.

Comment: A typical measurable set in your space could be: $\{\mu \in P(S) | \mu(B) \in A\},$ for some measurable sets $B$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}.$ This would be $\pi^{-1}_B(A)$. To see that the given map is measurable you have to apply the definition and check (for example along finite intersections of sets of the form given above), that the counterimage of a measurable set is measurable.

Comment: Can you prove it for me with details? I still have no idea how to prove it and the whole definition seems like abstract nonsense to be honest.